# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable (datetime)

Tags: python, datetime

I have a piece of code that i'm trying to run here :

```
data=pd.read_csv("../Generated Data/atp_data.csv")
data.Date = data.Date.apply(lambda x:datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%m/%d/%Y'))



beg = datetime(1,1,2008)
end = data.Date.iloc[-1]
indices = data[(data.Date>beg)&(data.Date<=end)].index
```

However, everytime i do, i am getting this error:

```
    beg = datetime(1,1,2008)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Can anyone solve this?

Comment: `datetime` is a module. `datetime.datetime` is a class.

Answer (score 0):

Your import statement should be `from datetime import datetime`.

Answer (score 0):

`datetime` is, infact, a module (doc [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html)). You should try this:

```
from datetime import date, datetime
beg_date = date(year=2008, month=1, day=1)
beg_datetime = datetime(year=2008, month=1, day=1)
```

or

```
import datetime

beg_date = datetime.date(year=2008, month=1, day=1)
beg_datetime = datetime.datetime(year=2008, month=1, day=1)
```